# Gray color output in folium choropleth

Tags: python, pandas, folium, choropleth

Hi I am new in Data Analytics, I have a problem with folium choropleth map, the color scale is not working in my map, it is showing gray color only.

[Folium Choropleth Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bycut.png)

[Folium Choropleth Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFD4k.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. This makes it much more difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error:

```
Key_on='feature.properties.ＭUNICIPALI',
```

Modify it as:

```
key_on='feature.properties.ＭUNICIPALI',
```

if that doesn't work, you should paste your code and dataset here